# Jasmine new function in function error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This is angular javascript source

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory('AAA', function(){
    return function(){
        return {
            say:function(){
            console.log('I am A');
            }
        };
    };
});

app.factory('helpMe', function(AAA){
    return function(){

        var type = new AAA();

        var play = function(){
            type.say();  
        };

        return {
            play:play
        }

    };
});
```

This is Jasmine Source

```
    it('helMe Test',function(){
        var helpMe = new helpMe();
        var AAA = new AAA();

        spyOn(AAA,'say');
        helpMe.play();
        expect(AAA.say).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

Jasmine souce is not working 
because new AAA() in helpMe factory, and new AAA in it(){} is different.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the whole point of dependency injection, which is precisely to avoid creating instances of collaborators, and let the framework inject them instead, to make the code testable.

Here's a rewritten version of your code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.factory('AAA', function() {
    return {
       say: function() {
           console.log('I am A');
       }
    };
});

app.factory('helpMe', function(AAA) {
    var play = function() {
        AAA.say();  
    };

    return {
        play: play
    };
});
```

And the test:

```
it('helMe Test', inject(function(AAA, helpMe) {
    spyOn(AAA, 'say');
    helpMe.play();
    expect(AAA.say).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```